# Redux store updates in asynchronous function, but container does not get props changes

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I' trying to make a real time application with react, redux and redux-thunk, that gets the objects from back-end through socket with STOMP over sockJS, and update redux store every time an object comes and finally updates the container when redux store updates.

My connect class through stomp over sockjs is this;

```
class SearcButtons extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="searchbuttons">
               <RaisedButton className="bttn" label="Start" onClick={() => this.start_twitter_stream()} />
               <RaisedButton  className="bttn" label="Start" onClick={() => this.stop_twitter_stream()} />
            </div>
        );
    }


   start_twitter_stream() {
        let stompClient = null;
        var that = this;
        let socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:3001/twitterStream');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.debug = null;
        stompClient.connect({}, function () {
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/fetchTwitterStream', function (tokenizedTweet) {
                let tweet = JSON.parse(tokenizedTweet.body);
                    let payload = {
                        data: {
                            tweets: that.props.state.reducer.tweets,
                        }
                    }
                    payload.data.tweets.push(
                        {
                            "username": tweet.username,
                            "tweet": tweet.tweet,
                        }
                    );
                    that.props.actions.update_tweets_data(payload);

            });
            stompClient.send("/app/manageTwitterStream", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'command': 'start', 'message': that.props.state.reducer.keyword }));
            let payload = {
                data: {
                    socketConnection: stompClient
                }
            }
            that.props.actions.start_twitter_stream(payload);

        });

    }
    stop_twitter_stream() {
        var socketConnection = this.props.state.reducer.socketConnection;
        socketConnection.send("/app/manageTwitterStream", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'command': 'stop', 'message': null }));
        socketConnection.disconnect();
        let payload = {
            data: {
                socketConnection: null
            }
        }
        return this.props.actions.stop_twitter_stream(payload);
    }

}

SearcButtons.propTypes = {
    actions: PropTypes.object,
    initialState: PropTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { state: state };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SearcButtons);
```

I'm calling tweet panel container inside App.js

```
import TweetPanel from './containers/TweetPanel';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div className="main">
                    <TweetPanel />
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>

        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

My container that listens redux-store is this;

```
class TweetPanel extends Component {
   const TABLE_COLUMNS = [
       {
           key: 'username',
           label: 'Username',
       }, {
           key: 'tweet',
          label: 'Tweet',
       },
   ];
render() {
        console.log(this.props);
         return (
            <DataTables
                height={'auto'}
                selectable={false}
                showRowHover={true}
                columns={TABLE_COLUMNS}
                data={   
                    (typeof (this.props.state.reducer.tweets) !== "undefined" ) ?this.props.state.reducer.tweets : []
                }
                showCheckboxes={false}
                onCellClick={this.handleCellClick}
                onCellDoubleClick={this.handleCellDoubleClick}
                onFilterValueChange={this.handleFilterValueChange}
                onSortOrderChange={this.handleSortOrderChange}
                page={1}
                count={100}
            />
        );


        }
    }
TweetPanel.propTypes = {
    actions: PropTypes.object,
    initialState: PropTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { state: state };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(TweetPanel);
```

My actions;

```
import {
    BUILD_TWITTER_STREAM,
    START_TWITTER_STREAM,
    UPDATE_TWEETS_DATA,

} from '../actions/action_types';

export function build_twitter_stream(state) {
    return {
        type: BUILD_TWITTER_STREAM,
        payload: state
    };
}
export function start_twitter_stream(state) {
    return {
        type: START_TWITTER_STREAM,
        payload: state
    };
}
export function update_tweets_data(state) {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_TWEETS_DATA,
        payload: state
    };

}
```

My reducer;

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

let initialState =  {

    socketConnection   : null,
    tweets             : [ ]         
}


export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {

        case BUILD_TWITTER_STREAM:
            return update(
                state, {
                    socketConnection: { $set: action.payload.data.socketConnection }
                }
            );

        case START_TWITTER_STREAM:
            return update(
                state, {
                    socketConnection: { $set: action.payload.data.socketConnection }
                }
            );
        case UPDATE_TWEETS_DATA:
            return update(
                state, {
                    tweets: { $merge: action.payload.data.tweets }
                }
            );
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My observations are when I try to connect to socket through stomp over Sockjs, I need to pass the context as named "that" variable which you can see the first code block above and update redux store with that context in stompClient's connect function's callback, which means I update store in an asynchronou function, redux store updates very well when I look to Chrome' s extension of Redux devtools, but container doesn't update unless I press to the stop button which triggers an action which is not asynchronous.

Thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: where you are using TweetPanel component?

Comment: Hi Akshay, I edited the question as your request.

Comment: It seems to me that you have problem in your reducer. Can you please add it here?
If you update state and you can see that change OK with Chrome extension, but component is not updated -> that means you are copying the old object and not creating new one.

Comment: @CorwinCZ I put the reducer and actions

Comment: The `update` function comes from which library? Can you please share it's declaration?

Comment: It comes from immutability helper library @CorwinCZ

Answer (score 1):

I can offer another approach, function delegate approach, since I have struggled by similar issiues. I create props in components, like your RaisedButton. For example I create BindStore props, such as:

```
<RaisedButton BindStore={(thatContext)=>{thatContext.state = AppStore.getState();}}... />
```

Also I can add subscriber props, such as:

```
<RaisedButton SubscribeStore={(thatContext) => {AppStore.subscribe(()=>{thatContext.setState(AppStore.getState())})}} ... />
```

At the RaisedButton.js, I can give thatContext easily:

```
...
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        if(this.props.BindStore){
          this.props.BindStore(this);
        }

        if(this.props.SubscribeStore){
          this.props.SubscribeStore(this);
        }

      }
...
```

Also by doing so, means by using props, one RaisedButton may not have BindingStore ability or SubscribeStore ability. Also by props I can call store dispatchers, such as:

```
 in parent.js:
 <RaisedButton PropsClick={(thatContext, thatValue) => {AppStore.dispacth(()=> 
  {type:"ActionType", payload:{...}})}} ... />

in RaisedButton.js
//as an example I used here dropDown, which is:
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown'; 
//react-native-material-dropdown package has issues but the solutions are in internet :)
...
render(){
  return(
     <View>
        <Dropdown onChangeText={(value) => {this.props.PropsClick(this, value);}}  />
     </View>
  )
}
...
```

In many examples, for instance your parent is SearchButtons, the parent must be rendered, the parent must subscribe the store so when any child changes the store all component cluster is rerendered. But, by this approach, children components are subscribed and bound to the store. Even one child may dispatch an action and after that, other same type children subscribed function is called back and only the subscribed children is rerendered. Also, you will connect only one component to the redux store, the parent.

```
//parent.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import AppStore from '../CustomReducer';
...

//you will not need to set your parent's state to store state.
```

I did not investigate very much about this approach but I do not use mapping functions. However, the child components will access all store datas, but also in mappings all store datas are also accessible.

Comment: I said that parent is connected to the store, Actually, there is no need to import connect package here. I have tested and children are dispatching actions and callback subscriptions work just fine.